# Twitch login | Swift

Tags: swift, twitch, twitch-api

i need to implement the Twitch login in swift app with [implicit-grant-flow](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/getting-tokens-oauth/#implicit-grant-flow)

I think i should use this [Authenticating a User Through a Web Service](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/authenticating_a_user_through_a_web_service) from apple for use a web authentication session to authenticate a user in my app (in this case Twitch login page).

I do not understand how can i catch the token after the login "Your app’s registered redirect URI. The access token is sent to this URI." , in my case i should set http://localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

Since Twitch doesn't support "device URLS" of the form `myapp://`

You should utilise a middle man server/webpage

1. Use the iOS function to open the URL to your middle man page
2. Middle man page redirects to Twitch
3. User accepts/declines the Connection
4. User comes back to your middle man page
5. Middle man page redirects to `myapp://auth/success?token=woo` or `myapp://auth/failed?error=whate`

This is on possible solution. And works for both kinds of oAuth (not that you'd generally use code flow here)

You could run an accounts system and then link Twitch to the account and then your app just logins into the accounts system and can use the linked Twitch Account.